# cakephp-3.4 immutable http\request api API

Tags: php, cakephp, immutability, cakephp-3.4

In cakephp 3.3 I could use statement like this in controller:

```
$this->request->data = array_merge($this->request->query,$this->request->data);
```

How can I achieve the same effect using new immutable http\request api API i n cake 3.4/3.5?

Comment: You are not supposed to modify the request data, it's considered bad practice. Changes in CakePHP 3.4 just prevent you from doing so. See [CakePHP 3.4, How to change Request data programmaticly](http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/cakephp-3-4-how-to-change-request-data-programmaticly/2120). If you let us know your particular use case, someone might be able to provide a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's quite bad practice to overwrite (or even append to) the request, since this is what the client has sent - if you really still want to go that way, one could use reflection to set the value... Did I mention this is bad practice?

Like.. really bad practice :)

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionObject($this->request);
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('data');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$reflectionProperty->setValue($this->request, -YourNewArray-);
```

I guess I don't have to repeat that what already has been said, but if it saves you the problem of upgrading between versions.. this might fix it.